# How to make an api Get request using @nestjs/axios

Tags: api, axios, httprequest, nestjs, httpmodule

I want to get weather info for a city from OpenWeatherMap but I get a weird JSON response

[image]

Response the I got

{
"name": "dallas",
"weather": {
"source": {
"source": {}
}
},
"_id": "61c335daeb8c6b030489996b",
"__v": 0
}

`cities.service.ts`

```
@Injectable()
export class CitiesService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel('City') private readonly cityModel: Model<City>,
    private readonly httpService: HttpService
  ) {}

  async createCity(createCityDto: CreateCityDto) {
    const { name } = createCityDto;

    // Get city weather from OpenWeatherMap
    const weather = await this.httpService
      .get(
        `api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${name}&appid=${process.env.OPEN_WEATHER_API_KEY}`,
      )
      .pipe(
        map((response) => response.data),
        map((data) => data),
      );

    console.log(weather);

    const city = new this.cityModel({
      name,
      weather,
    });

    await city.save();

    return city;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@nestjs/axios` wraps all of the HTTP calls in [RxJS Observables](https://rxjs.dev) which are kind of like supercharged callbacks. Once you open an observable stream, you either need to only work inside that stream (using the `.pipe` and operators as you've started for mapping the data) or you need to convert the Observable to a promise. The easiest way to do that is to use `lastValueFrom` and wrap the entire Observbale with it (`lastValueFrom(this.http.get().pipe())`). If you go with the former, `tap` and `switchMap` will probably be two operators to get the hang of as well, otherwise the `lastValueFrom` approach can be `await`ed as a normal promise.

Comment: Thank you so much!